# Calculating distance between two points on a flat plane? (php)

Tags: php, distance, points, flat

3rd grade question:

How do you calculate the distance between two points on a flat surface?

I have been going through the [Google_Results](http://www.google.com/q=distance+between+two+points+php) and it seems everything i find applies to Long/Lat and not a flat surface.

I'm working on making ObjectA choose between ObjetsC,D,E... , select the closest one and move toward it. So I have to loop through my SQL table, pull out what's in range, and loop through the results to calculate distances.

Any help with this math I haven't had to remember in years would be appreciated.

Comment: Difference between horizontal 1 and horizontal 2, and vertical 1 and vertical 2, and then pythagoras

Comment: Pythagoras:Pythagoras of Samos was an Ionian Greek philosopher, and founder of the religious movement called Pythagoreanism. maybe you should talk to me like i'm a 3rd grader, because i don't know what a philosopher has to do with math.

Comment: as you can clearly use Google, Pythagoras of Samos was also a mathematician (a lot of philosophy back in those days was mathematics) and came up with what is called "Pythagoras Theorem" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: because i have enough to do without spending 20 minutes reading a typical Wikipedia biography just to find a simple formula.

Comment: a) it wouldn't take 20 minutes, b) the Pythagorean theorem is widely known, c) it took **just as long to post the question here**

Comment: @WaxyChicken - but you're more than happy to let us spend our time doing the work for you... now I'm downvoting because you've admitted you're too bloody lazy

Comment: no one forces you to answer questions. And there's a difference between not-enough-time-becuase-youre-overworked and not-enough-time-because-you-want-to-cut-your-toenails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use a [Euclidean distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions) (specifically for 2 dimensions).  Basically the formula is:

```
d = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
```

- `d` is your final distance
- `sqrt` is the square root (the [`sqrt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) function in PHP)
- `x1` and `y1` are your x-y coordinates for your first point
- `x2` and `y2` are your x-y coordinates for your second point
- `^2` means raise to the second power (use the [`pow()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function for PHP)

[Pythagoras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras) was the Greek philosopher who developed the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), which can be used to derive the 2-dimensional distance formula (which is different from [Euclid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid)'s derivation).